# Unknown column when trying to use JSON_EXTRACT in where clause

Tags: 8

This query is working directly in Mysql:

> SELECT entity_id FROM node__field_json WHERE
> JSON_EXTRACT(field_json_value, "$.mpk") = '014005'

I cannot make it working in Drupal:

```
$query = 'SELECT entity_id FROM node__field_json WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(field_json_value, "$.mpk") = :symbol';
$result = $this->database->query($query, [':symbol' => '014005'])->execute();
```

An error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '$.mpk' in
> 'where clause': SELECT entity_id FROM node__field_json WHERE
> JSON_EXTRACT(field     _json_value, "$.mpk") = :symbol; Array
> (
>
> ```
>   [:symbol] => 014005                                                                                                                               > )
> ```

Comment: Have you tried single quotes around `$.mpk`?

Comment: @Clive thanks a lot working, but only when I put variable in SQL string, so I cannot use :param anymore